# Find sequence $c_n$ such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}c_n^2=1$ and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}c_{n+1}c_n=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to see if it is true that there exists a sequence of real numbers $c_n$ such that

1. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_n <\infty$
2. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}c_n^2=1$
3. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}c_{n+1}c_n=1$

For cases 1) and 2) I can obviously choose $c_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{|n|}}}$
and I think that for cases 1) and 3) I can find $c_n$ such that $c_{n+1}c_n=\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{|n|}}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, given a "good" first step of the recursive sequence.

The problem lies in satisfying 2) and 3). My mind is completely stuck right now. I would be happy with a proof or even a disproof.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, $$\left|\sum_n c_n c_{n+1}\right| \le \sum_n c_n^2$$ with equality only if all $c_n = k c_{n+1}$ for some constant $k$.  But such a sequence is either all $0$ or not square-summable.

Comment: Yes right! Many thanks!